# Problems installing MySQL on Mac OSX 10.11.3 El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos

I am installing MySQL onto my machine using the website's .dmg file, but I'm running into issues. I've also tried installing it using brew, but did not have any success.

After finishing the installation I changed my directory to /usr/local/bin and executed 'mysqld_safe &' and got the following response

```html
>16:52:43 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql-5.5.46-osx10.8-x86_64/data/{computer_name}.local.err'.

>16:52:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.46-osx10.8-x86_64/data 160321

>16:52:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.46-osx10.8-x86_64/data/{computer_name}.local.pid ended
```

When I tried running sudo mysql_secure_installation I received the following:

> Enter current password for root (enter for none):  ERROR 2002 (HY000):
>   Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
>   (2)

I'm not sure what the issue is and I have been able to run MySQL before and tried reinstalling it after the server stopped running. I've tried many different solutions without much success.

Has anyone run into issues installing this on the latest OS? If so, what is the fix? Is it a permission issue? Thanks!

Comment: try :  mysqld_safe --user=mysql &

Comment: @BernBuffen I tried this and I received the same responses. What should I expect when I run mysqld_safe?